# why image is saving as text file in node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, multer

Here i'm trying to save the image in database using `multer` but image type is saving as a text format but not in .png , .jpeg, .jpg format,

PLease help me where i'm doing wrong thanks in advance

Schema:-

```
module.exports = mongoose => {

const Role = mongoose.model(
  "role",
  mongoose.Schema(
    {
     roleType : { type:String },
     image: {  type: String,
      data: Buffer}
    }
  )
);
return Role;
```

};

controller (Creating an instance):-

```
exports.addRoleFields = async (req, res) => {
   const rolesList = new Role ({     
  roleType : req.body.roleType,
  roleImg  : req.file.path,
});
rolesList
.save(rolesList)   
  .then(data => {
    res.status(200).send({ data, statusCode: "200" });
  })
  .catch(err => {
    res.status(500).send({
      message: err.message || "Some error occurred while creating.",
      statusCode: "500"
    });
  })
 }
 }
```

routes:-

```
   module.exports = app => {

    const multer = require("multer"),
       storage = multer.diskStorage({
         destination: function(req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, 'uploads')
         },
         filename: function(req, file, cb) {
         cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
        }
       })
  const uploadImg = multer({storage: storage}).single('image');
  
  const roles = require("../controllers/roles.js");
  var router = require("express").Router();
   router.post("/addRole", uploadImg , roles.addRoleFields);
  app.use('/api/roles', router);
 };
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I simply changed  this

```
 filename: function(req, file, cb) {
     cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now())
  }
```

to

```
filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
}
```

its working and saving the file

Answer (score 0):

try this for mongodb client

```
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: async function (req, file, cb) {
        let path = 'uploads/' + req.body.path;
        if (!fs.existsSync(path)) {
            fs.mkdirSync(path, { recursive: true }, (err) => {
                if (err) throw err;
            });
        }
        await cb(null, path);
    },
    filename: function (req, file, cb) {

        cb(null, req.body.filename)
    }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: storage })

const router = express.Router();

// Upload Image
router.post("/upload", upload.single('image'), (req, res, next) => {
    return res.json({
        image: req.file.path
    });
});
```

in this `upload.single('image')`, file should be the name in which formdata carries the file.
in your case,

```
 router.post("/addRole", uploadImg('image'), (req, res)=>{
});
```

Comment: I used this , but getting same issue at the above code you can see the postman i'm using from-data .

Comment: ` router.post("/addRole", uploadImg('image'), (req, res)=>{
});` check this. I dont have much idea about mongoose. But mongoclient it can be easily done

Comment: got this error `Cannot read property 'transfer-encoding' of undefined`

Comment: try this ` router.post("/addRole", uploadImg , (req,res)=>{ console.log(req.file)});

Comment: {
  fieldname: 'image',
  originalname: 'saree.jpg',
  encoding: '7bit',
  mimetype: 'image/jpeg',
  destination: 'uploads',
  filename: 'roleImg-1626417263461',
  path: 'uploads\\roleImg-1626417263461',
  size: 95917
}

i got this data

Comment: in your routes `  destination: function(req, file, cb) {
          cb(null, 'uploads')
         },` change 'uploads' to 'uploads/'

Comment: cb(null, file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now().jpg) .... give extension for the file name

Comment: we can't fix it to .jpg format because every time it will be diiferent

Comment: try this   filename: function(req, file, cb) {
            let x = req.body.filename.split('.');
            let ext = req.body.filename[x.length - 1];
            let newFileName = file.fieldname + '-' + Date.now() + "." + ext;
            cb(null, newFileName)
        }

Comment: please look at my answer i have posted

Answer (score 0):

**mongoose model**

```js
const imgSave = new mongoose.Schema({
    img:{
        data: Buffer,
        contentType: String
    }
});
```

Comment: img is not saving in db